# link time error in vc++ when using confuse library

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I am trying to use confuse library on windows. I get a link time  error when confuse is compiled in vc++. how to resolve it. Please note that libConfuse is a configuration file parser library  and written in C.

```
1>Linking...
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_opt_getnint referenced in function "void __cdecl print_ask(struct cfg_opt_t *,unsigned int,struct _iobuf *)" (?print_ask@@YAXPAUcfg_opt_t@@IPAU_iobuf@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_title referenced in function "int __cdecl cb_validate_bookmark(struct cfg_t *,struct cfg_opt_t *)" (?cb_validate_bookmark@@YAHPAUcfg_t@@PAUcfg_opt_t@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getstr referenced in function "int __cdecl cb_validate_bookmark(struct cfg_t *,struct cfg_opt_t *)" (?cb_validate_bookmark@@YAHPAUcfg_t@@PAUcfg_opt_t@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_opt_getnsec referenced in function "int __cdecl cb_validate_bookmark(struct cfg_t *,struct cfg_opt_t *)" (?cb_validate_bookmark@@YAHPAUcfg_t@@PAUcfg_opt_t@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_opt_size referenced in function "int __cdecl cb_validate_bookmark(struct cfg_t *,struct cfg_opt_t *)" (?cb_validate_bookmark@@YAHPAUcfg_t@@PAUcfg_opt_t@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_free referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_print referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_set_print_func referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getnint referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getnfloat referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getnstr referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getsec referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getbool referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getnsec referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_size referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_setstr referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_getint referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_parse referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_set_validate_func referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_init referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cfg_include referenced in function _main
1>F:\products\testconfuse\testconfuse\Debug\testconfuse.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\products\testconfuse\testconfuse\testconfuse\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>testconfuse - 22 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

The program has two file main.cpp and test.conf . Also not that we need to download http://bzero.se/confuse/confuse-2.6.zip and give use library libConfuse.lib which is present inside confuse-2.6\windows\msvc6\libConfuse

```
///// main.cpp

extern "C"
{
    #include <confuse.h>
}
#include <string.h>

void print_func(cfg_opt_t *opt, unsigned int index, FILE *fp)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s(foo)", opt->name);
}

void print_ask(cfg_opt_t *opt, unsigned int index, FILE *fp)
{
    int value = cfg_opt_getnint(opt, index);
    switch(value) {
        case 1:
            fprintf(fp, "yes");
            break;
        case 2:
            fprintf(fp, "no");
            break;
        case 3:
        default:
            fprintf(fp, "maybe");
            break;
    }
}

/* function callback
 */
int cb_func(cfg_t *cfg, cfg_opt_t *opt, int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int i;

    /* at least one parameter is required */
    if(argc == 0) {
        cfg_error(cfg, "Too few parameters for the '%s' function",
                  opt->name);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("cb_func() called with %d parameters:\n", argc);
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("parameter %d: '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

/* value parsing callback
 *
 * VALUE must be "yes", "no" or "maybe", and the corresponding results
 * are the integers 1, 2 and 3.
 */
int cb_verify_ask(cfg_t *cfg, cfg_opt_t *opt, const char *value, void *result)
{
    if(strcmp(value, "yes") == 0)
        *(long int *)result = 1;
    else if(strcmp(value, "no") == 0)
        *(long int *)result = 2;
    else if(strcmp(value, "maybe") == 0)
        *(long int *)result = 3;
    else {
        cfg_error(cfg, "Invalid value for option %s: %s", opt->name, value);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int cb_validate_bookmark(cfg_t *cfg, cfg_opt_t *opt)
{
    /* only validate the last bookmark */
    cfg_t *sec = cfg_opt_getnsec(opt, cfg_opt_size(opt) - 1);
    if(!sec)
    {
        cfg_error(cfg, "section is NULL!?");
        return -1;
    }
    if(cfg_getstr(sec, "machine") == 0)
    {
        cfg_error(cfg, "machine option must be set for bookmark '%s'",
                  cfg_title(sec));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int i;
    cfg_t *cfg;
    unsigned n;
    int ret;
    static cfg_opt_t proxy_opts[] = {
        CFG_INT("type", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR("host", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR_LIST("exclude", "{localhost, .localnet}", CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_INT("port", 21, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_END()
    };
    static cfg_opt_t bookmark_opts[] = {
        CFG_STR("machine", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_INT("port", 21, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR("login", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR("password", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR("directory", 0, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_BOOL("passive-mode", cfg_false, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_SEC("proxy", proxy_opts, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_END()
    };
    cfg_opt_t opts[] = {
        CFG_INT("backlog", 42, CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_STR("probe-device", "eth2", CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_SEC("bookmark", bookmark_opts, CFGF_MULTI | CFGF_TITLE),
        CFG_FLOAT_LIST("delays", "{3.567e2, 0.2, -47.11}", CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_FUNC("func", &cb_func),
        CFG_INT_CB("ask-quit", 3, CFGF_NONE, &cb_verify_ask),
        CFG_INT_LIST_CB("ask-quit-array", "{maybe, yes, no}",
                        CFGF_NONE, &cb_verify_ask),
        CFG_FUNC("include", &cfg_include),
        CFG_END()
    };

#ifndef _WIN32
    /* for some reason, MS Visual C++ chokes on this (?) */
    printf("Using %s\n\n", confuse_copyright);
#endif

    cfg = cfg_init(opts, CFGF_NOCASE);

    /* set a validating callback function for bookmark sections */
    cfg_set_validate_func(cfg, "bookmark", &cb_validate_bookmark);

    ret = cfg_parse(cfg, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "test.conf");
    printf("ret == %d\n", ret);
    if(ret == CFG_FILE_ERROR) {
        perror("test.conf");
        return 1;
    } else if(ret == CFG_PARSE_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "parse error\n");
        return 2;
    }

    printf("backlog == %ld\n", cfg_getint(cfg, "backlog"));

    printf("probe device is %s\n", cfg_getstr(cfg, "probe-device"));
    cfg_setstr(cfg, "probe-device", "lo");
    printf("probe device is %s\n", cfg_getstr(cfg, "probe-device"));

    n = cfg_size(cfg, "bookmark");
    printf("%d configured bookmarks:\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cfg_t *pxy;
        cfg_t *bm = cfg_getnsec(cfg, "bookmark", i);
        printf("  bookmark #%u (%s):\n", i+1, cfg_title(bm));
        printf("    machine = %s\n", cfg_getstr(bm, "machine"));
        printf("    port = %d\n", (int)cfg_getint(bm, "port"));
        printf("    login = %s\n", cfg_getstr(bm, "login"));
        printf("    passive-mode = %s\n",
               cfg_getbool(bm, "passive-mode") ? "true" : "false");
        printf("    directory = %s\n", cfg_getstr(bm, "directory"));
        printf("    password = %s\n", cfg_getstr(bm, "password"));

        pxy = cfg_getsec(bm, "proxy");
        if(pxy) {
            int j, m;
            if(cfg_getstr(pxy, "host") == 0) {
                printf("      no proxy host is set, setting it to 'localhost'...\n");
                /* For sections without CFGF_MULTI flag set, there is
                 * also an extended syntax to get an option in a
                 * subsection:
                 */
                cfg_setstr(bm, "proxy|host", "localhost");
            }
            printf("      proxy host is %s\n", cfg_getstr(pxy, "host"));
            printf("      proxy type is %ld\n", cfg_getint(pxy, "type"));
            printf("      proxy port is %ld\n", cfg_getint(pxy, "port"));

            m = cfg_size(pxy, "exclude");
            printf("      got %d hosts to exclude from proxying:\n", m);
            for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                printf("        exclude %s\n", cfg_getnstr(pxy, "exclude", j));
            }
        } else
            printf("    no proxy settings configured\n");
    }

    printf("delays are (%d):\n", cfg_size(cfg, "delays"));
    for(i = 0; i < cfg_size(cfg, "delays"); i++)
        printf(" %G\n", cfg_getnfloat(cfg, "delays", i));

    printf("ask-quit == %ld\n", cfg_getint(cfg, "ask-quit"));

    /* Using cfg_setint(), the integer value for the option ask-quit
     * is not verified by the value parsing callback.
     *
     *
     cfg_setint(cfg, "ask-quit", 4);
     printf("ask-quit == %ld\n", cfg_getint(cfg, "ask-quit"));
    */

    /* The following commented line will generate a failed assertion
     * and abort, since the option "foo" is not declared
     *
     *
     printf("foo == %ld\n", cfg_getint(cfg, "foo"));
    */

    cfg_addlist(cfg, "ask-quit-array", 2, 1, 2);

    for(i = 0; i < cfg_size(cfg, "ask-quit-array"); i++)
        printf("ask-quit-array[%d] == %ld\n",
               i, cfg_getnint(cfg, "ask-quit-array", i));

    /* print the parsed values to another file */
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("test.conf.out", "w");
        cfg_set_print_func(cfg, "func", print_func);
        cfg_set_print_func(cfg, "ask-quit", print_ask);
        cfg_set_print_func(cfg, "ask-quit-array", print_ask);
        cfg_print(cfg, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    cfg_free(cfg);
    return 0;
}

//  test.conf
# test config file

# this is a one line comment

// this is a C++-style one line comment

/*
 * This is a C-style multi-line comment
 */

BackLog = 2147483647

bookmark heimdal {
    login = "anonymous"
    password = ${ANONPASS:-anonymous@}
    directory = "/pub/heimdal/src"
    machine = "ftp://ftp.pdc.kth.se:21"

    proxy {
      type = 1
      host = ${HOST:-localhost}   # environment variable substitution
      #port = 21
      #exclude = {"localhost"  , ".localnet" , "fu.bar.net"}
      exclude += {.aol.com , .sf.net}
    }
}

probe-device = "eth1"
# probe-device += "eth3"   # error, probe-device is not a list

bookmark gazonk {
 machine = "ssh://localhost"
 login = joe
 passive-mode = true
 directory = '/pub/dir with spaces/\
more'       # continued on next line
  port = 022 # in octal mode
 proxy {} /* use default proxy */
}

bookmark ftp.du.se {
 machine = "ftp.du.se"
// port = 0x21 /* hexadecimal */
 login = ftp
 proxy {
   exclude = {.com.net}
 }
}

/* functions can be called with variable number of arguments
 */
func( "one", "two", 'three',four )
func( 1, 2 )

//delays = {145.12345, .6,42, 4.987e2}
//delays += {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}

ask-quit = maybe

#ask-quit-array = {"maybe", "maybe", "maybe"}
ask-quit-array += {"no", "yes", "yes"}

include(inc.conf)

/////////////////////////////////
```

---

I have added libconfuse.lib inside linker->input->"additional depenendencies" and  also given path of lib linker->General ->"additional link directory"

---

I have added libconfuse 2.6 and extracted it. I have used lib in it also config.h from its src dir. I have then compiled example program from libconfuse home page.

Comment: Please edit your question to update it instead of writing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt add a reference to a lib that is needed for the "confuselib" to work. Can you check your compiler linker includes and see if you added all the relevant confuse libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

those methods are all defined in confuse.c; either you are not linking with the confuse library, or with another version, or you built the confuse library with an erroneous configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed now . it was resolved when i gave lib path from  F:\confuse-2.6\windows\msvc6\libConfuse to F:\confuse-2.6\windows\msvs.net\libConfuse\Release